# what is command to find acl users count in redis db?

Tags: redis

I am new to redis db ,I need only count of acl users.
If I run below command it will return list of users but i need only count.

command I am running is

```
ACL LIST
```

Returns

```
"user default on nopass ~* &* +@all"
```

but i need command which will return count e.g 1

Thanks In advance

Comment: `ACL LIST | wc -l`

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 ACL LIST | wc -l
```